# При попытке компиляции игры под андроид возникает:CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed

Tags: android, unity3d, gradle

Не могу понять, в чем возникает ошибка при компиляции игры под андроид. Открыл через андроид студию, там ошибки не выдает. Файл build.gradle вроде настроил, как нужно.

Текст ошибки:

```
    CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
    C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.2.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"
    
    stderr[
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\UnityProjects\New Year's Trouble\Temp\gradleOut\build.gradle' line: 23

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradleOut'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.6. Current version is 4.2.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\UnityProjects\New Year's Trouble\Temp\gradleOut\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.6-all.zip

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0021f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:187 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:94 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

[image: скрин ошибки в самой Unity]

Текст файла build.gradle:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
    }
    allprojects {
    repositories {
        repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        }
    }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    }
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        applicationId 'com.AlexGame.Troubles'
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'x86'
        }
        versionCode 1
        versionName '0.1'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/x86/*.so'
    }
    }
```

Comment: Rebuild/clean project, Invalidate cache and restart уже делали?

Comment: В андроид студии проблем не возникает со сборкой проекта. Все проблемы появляются в Unity

Comment: https://youtu.be/LXiptHLv5hU в этом видео все объяснили все кратко и ясно

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло вот что:

1. Андроид Студио File>Settings>Android SDK убрал галку с последней 10-й версии и заменил ее на 9-й андроид.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Юнити File>Build Settings>Player Settings>Other Settings>Identification>Target API Level установил на тот же 9-й андроид взамен Automatic (highest installed) того что стоит по-умолчанию.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Ну и в Package Name названия привел к нижнему регистру. ХЗ повлияло ли, но на всякий случай лучше сделать так.